# nginx, rewrite, API and spaces in parameters

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

We're struggling with fellow sysadmins with a lighhtpd->nginx/1.8.1 migration and rewrite rules.

We have an API and a rewrite rule like this (in nginx) :

```
rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api.php?action=$1 last;
```

In my PHP API, I split the "actions" in an array, with the explode PHP function.
Therefore, `GET /api/article/search&key=AUTHENTIFICATION_KEY&q=SEARCH_QUERY`
rewrites to `/api.php?action=article/search&key=AUTHENTIFICATION_KEY&q=SEARCH_QUERY`

The PHP system array `$_GET` contains

```
"action'" => "article/search"
"key"=>"AUTHENTIFICATION_KEY"
"q"=>SEARCH_QUERY
```

So far so good... Except when there is a space in the search query, like this:

```
GET /api/article/search&key=AUTHENTIFICATION_KEY&q=SEARCH QUERY&blabla=lol&test=wes (last parameters given as examples)
```

I don't know why but in this case, the & character in the URL seems to be escaped. Therefore, my `PHP $_GET` array only has on field: the entire string after /api.

`["action"] => "article/search&key=AUTHENTIFICATION_KEY&q=SEARCH QUERY&blabla=lol&test=wes"`
and `$_GET[['key'], $_GET['q'] etc are empty` ...

Any idea?

EDIT : however, everything works fine if I use proxy_pass with a location :

```
    location ~ /api/(.*) {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/api.php?action=$1;
```

but I have the feeling that his solution is really ugly ... Not to mention that we would have a LOT of rewrite rules to manually re-write (lol, re-code, in the config file) from lighttp to nginx

**EDIT : actually, I think that @Alexey asked the right question! When we were using lighttpd, the first GET parameter is set in the rewrite rule, with "?", then.
Nginx doesn't seem to work that way when the URL is encoded, even with "?" in the rewrite rule, the first GET parameter has to be set with "?", not "&".
We're running some test but it looks like that**

```
GET /api/article/search?key=AUTHENTIFICATION_KEY&q=SEARCH QUERY&blabla=lol&test=yes
```

**works :)**

Comment: But why do you use `&` instead of `?` ?

Comment: When you make the request, try to urlencode the values in the request. See if that helps.``GET /api/article/search&key=AUTHENTIFICATION_KEY&q=SEARCH%20QUERY&blabla=lol&test=wes``

Comment: @AlexeyTen because I use "?" in the rewrite, to introduce the GET parameter "action".
Firefox or PowerShell InvokeRestmethod automatically encodes the request, I can see it in nginx logs. When I use proxypass on the other hand, the request is not encoded and then it works.

Comment: You should use `GET /api/article/search?key=...`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem with the following setup, But i got a different output,which is what you had expect.

code in api.php

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

config in nginx.conf

```
rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api.php?action=$1 last;
```

With request

```
"GET /api/article/search&key=AUTHENTIFICATION_KEY&q=SEARCH QUERY&blabla=lol&test=wes HTTP/1.1"
```

The output is exactly what you'd expect.

```
array(5) {
  ["action"]=>
  string(14) "article/search"
  ["key"]=>
  string(20) "AUTHENTIFICATION_KEY"
  ["q"]=>
  string(12) "SEARCH QUERY"
  ["blabla"]=>
  string(3) "lol"
  ["test"]=>
  string(3) "wes"
}
```

**EDIT**

With further test, if you have url_encoded strings in your request, Nginx (or PHP itself) will url_encode the request first, which will escape the character '&' and when you output the PHP variable $_GET, It will be automatically url_decoded, So the whole request will be treated as the value of var action.

**So check your code to see if you had url_encoded any value before making the request.**

Comment: Hi and thanks for your time!

Actually, for testing purposes, my api.php does nothing more than a print_r($_REQUEST), for now.
I don't do any manual url_encoding but nginx (or php?) still escape the ? and & ...
Any idea? nginx or php misconfiguration maybe? I'm using php-fpm without any special tweak.

Nginx 1.8.1
Php 5.4.45-1

Comment: Also, a friend is testing it on his server, with nginx 1.10.0 and php7-fpm, without any special configuration, his result is the same as mine...

Comment: Ok I think I just understood what you meant. I'm using Firefox or PowerShell for my tests and wes they seem to encode ::space:: in %20. I don't want to avoid that, most of the clients do it. I'm looking for a solution server-side.

Comment: @nerthazrim In that case i think you might need a new rewrite rule.

Comment: I think that Alexei asked the right question. Nginx and lighttpd don't seem to have the same behavior.